# Warning: deprecated conversion from string constant

Tags: c++, linux, qt

Tengo un warning que no puedo quitar...el mismo me dice "deprecated conversion from string constant to char*".
El código donde se queja es el siguiente:

```
class THREE_DATA_4_COMPUTE
{
    public:
        THREE_DATA_4_COMPUTE(const QString &cn, char* umn = "", const QString &un = (const QString)"")
        {
            this->curveName = cn;
            this->unitModuleName = umn;
            this->unitName = un;
        };
        QString curveName;
        char* unitModuleName;
        QString unitName;
    protected:
        THREE_DATA_4_COMPUTE(){};
};
```

y yo la invoco de la siguiente forma, pasandolé 1 solo parámetro (de ahi que necesito los defaults):

```
THREE_DATA_4_COMPUTE *aux = new THREE_DATA_4_COMPUTE(this->getRmft());
```

Que es lo que está mal?. Estoy con c++, Qt 4.8 y linux.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
THREE_DATA_4_COMPUTE(const QString &cn, char* umn = "", const QString &un = (const QString)"")
//                                                  ^^                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//                                                   1                       2
```

Esos dos errores:

1. `""`no es una cadena variable sino constante, al igual que `"hola"` y en consecuencia únicamente debería apuntarse a dicha cadena desde un puntero constante
2. Esa estructura no tiene ningún sentido. Un objeto no constante puede pasar a ser constante cuando quiera sin penalización porque lo único que consigues así es aumentar la restricción del objeto y eso **siempre** está permitido. Por otro lado, no es necesario construir el `QString` a partir de una cadena porque ya tiene un constructor para ello

¿Cómo debería quedar ese constructor?

```
THREE_DATA_4_COMPUTE(const QString &cn, const char* umn = "", const QString &un = QString())
```

Un problema al que te puedes enfrentar al probar esta firma es que ahora `umn` no es compatible con `unitModuleName`, ya que uno es `const char*` y el otro `char*`. En mi opinión, salvo que sea estrictamente necesario, convertiría `unitModuleName` a `QString`... aunque lo mismo te vale con cambiar `unitModuleName` para que sea `const char*`... como no muestras la implementación de la clase no queda claro si ese valor puede cambiar o no.

Por supuesto, dado que es gratis poner nombres más largos a las variables, por legibilidad casi te aconejaría que los nombres de las mismas fuesen más descriptivos.

Answer (score 2):

#### Problema.

La alarma `deprecated conversion from string constant to char*` se suele dar al intentar almacenar literal de texto cuyo tipo es puntero constante a `char`, en una variable que es puntero a `char` (sin ser constante).

También puedes encontrar esta alarma cuando intentas almacenar un puntero constante a `char` en un puntero a `char` no constante.

#### Ejemplos.

```
void funcion(char *texto);

// deprecated conversion from string constant to char*
funcion("Patatas fritas, que ricas!");
```

En el código anterior vemos como un literal de texto (`"Patatas fritas, que ricas!"`) es almacenado en una variable de tipo puntero a `char` sin el calificador `const`. El tipo del literal de texto es `const char[27]` (arreglo constante de 27 elementos de tipo `char`), este tipo de arreglos es convertible implícitamente a puntero constante a `char`; al pasarlo a puntero no constante aparece la alarma. Para corregir el problema añade el calificador `const` al parámetro:

```
void funcion(const char *texto); // const anyadido
funcion("Patatas fritas, que ricas!"); // ninguna alarma
```

También puede suceder si el retorno de una función es `const char *` y se almacena en una variable puntero a `char` que no tenga el calificador `const`:

```
struct C { const char *miembro() { return nullptr; } };
void funcion(char *texto);

C c;

// deprecated conversion from string constant to char*
funcion(c.miembro());
```

#### ¿Por qué sucede?: Compatibilidad con [c](/questions/tagged/c)

La conversión implícita de `const char *` a `char *` es la única conversión de ese tipo permitida en C++, existe por retrocompatibilidad con C.

En el lenguaje C las semánticas de los literales de texto y del calificador `const` son diferentes que en C++. En C un literal de texto es un arreglo de `char` no constante mientras que en C++ un literal de texto es un arreglo de `char` constante. Para permitir las mismas semánticas en C que en C++ se marcó esta conversión como alarma en lugar de como error.

Así pues, en C pasar un literal de texto a una función está permitido:

```
// Si compilamos con C en lugar de con C++ ...
void funcion(char *texto);

// ... esto no da problemas ni alarmas.
funcion("Patatas fritas, que ricas!");
```

Sin embargo, las conversiones de datos calificados con `const` a datos sin cualificación está explícitamente prohibida en C++:

```
// Funcion que recibe un puntero a char
void funcion(char *texto);
// Funcion que recibe un puntero a int
void funcion_int(int *números);
// Un arreglo de valores int.
const int numeros[]{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

// deprecated conversion from string constant to char*
funcion("Patatas fritas, que ricas!");
// Error! NO se puede convertir 'const int *' a 'int *'.
funcion_int(numeros);
```

Mientras que con `char` obtenemos la alarma de *deprecated* con `int` recibimos un error. Si usas compiladores más modernos de C++ obtendrás un error en lugar de una alarma.

Comment: Lo que realmente necesito es utilizar el parametro default que tengo en el constructor. La teoría que me das ya la había visto, pero a mi entender no me sirve para resolver el parametro default en el constructor. Igualmente gracias por responder

Comment: No te estoy dando ninguna teoría, la alarma surge por los motivos que he expuesto. Puedes solucionar tu problema (conservando el default) cualificando el parámetro `char *` como `const char *` (como ya he comentado en la respuesta).