# ¿Por qué me dice error: deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>
char *preorden="GEAIBMCLDFKJH";//linea 5
char *inorden="IABEGLDCFMKHJ";//linea 6
char *postorden;

 void post(char *pre, char *in, char *pos, int n)
 {
     int longIzqda;

     if(n!=0) {
         pos[n-1]=pre[0];
         longIzqda=strchr(in,pre[0])-in;
         post(pre+1,in,pos,longIzqda);
         post(pre+1+longIzqda,in+1+longIzqda,pos+longIzqda,n-1-longIzqda);
     }
 }

 int main(int argc,char *argv[])
 {
     int aux;
     aux=strlen(preorden);
     postorden=(char *)malloc(aux*sizeof(char));
     if (postorden) {
         printf("El preorden es: %s\n",preorden);
         printf("El inorden es: %s\n",inorden);
         post(preorden,inorden,postorden,aux);
         postorden[aux]='\0';
         printf("El postorden calculado es: %s\n",postorden);
         free(postorden);
     } else {
         fprintf(stderr,"Error: Sin memoria\n");
         return 1;
     }
     return 0;
 }
```

Comment: ¿ Podrías indicar la línea en la que te lanza dicho *aviso* ? Para no dejarnos los ojillos mirando 45 líneas de código :-)

Comment: son las líneas 5 y 6

Comment: @Laura si la respuesta te ha ayudado, ¿puedes marcarla como válida?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema reside en que estas pasando cadenas constantes a una función que recibe `char*`.
Dado que no vas a modificar esas cadenas dentro de la función te sugiero lo siguiente.

Modifica la cabecera de la función de la siguiente manera:

```
void post(const char *pre, const char *in, char *pos, int n)
```

y las cadenas:

```
const char *preorden="GEAIBMCLDFKJH";
const char *inorden="IABEGLDCFMKHJ";
```

> Esta es una [pregunta relacionada del sitio en inglés](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/50763/warning-deprecated-conversion-from-string-constant)